# Why is there a time beetle on Donna's back in The Stolen Earth?

Tags: doctor-who

There was a time beetle in the episode *Turn Left* and it died after Rose helped to revert the changed history. So what is it doing on Donna’s back on the Shadow Proclamation station in *The Stolen Earth*?

Comment: It's not. What makes you think it is?

Comment: The servant at the station says, "there was something on your back", not "there IS something on your back". See also [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6204/why-did-so-many-people-feel-sorry-for-donna-noble).

Comment: I think there was also the time beetle's sound on the station. Or not? I'll have a look.

Comment: @MrLister thanks, I thought the servant said "there IS ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no beetle on her back in that episode, but the servant can still "see" it. The servant is part of a time-aware species, so she can see elements of Donna's past and future. She can "see" the insect because it was previously present, and she can "see" the tragedy in Donna's future as well. But note that, in *Turn Left*, whenever someone saw the beetle on Donna's back, it was also briefly shown on-screen (i.e. the *viewer* also sees it), something that never happened in *Stolen Earth*.

According to the closed captioning, the servant does say "There *was* something on your back",  which makes sense in that context -- she's commenting on Donna's recent history. But I admit the dialog isn't terribly clear, and given the number of times we hear "There *is* something on your back" in *Turn Left* it's easy enough to mis-hear the servant use the present tense instead.